# LaunchActivity not displaying correct layout

Tags: android, launch

I have a launch activity with this layout, which merely shows an image in the center.

However, only blank black page is shown, and then it jumps to the targeted class.

The problem is the launch activity is not shown as that in activity_launch.xml... What is the problem?

activity_launch.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".app.LaunchActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:background="#0064B0">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_property_finder" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
public class LaunchActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the manifest for the LaunchActivity:
manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".app.BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

    <!-- App Pages -->
    <activity
        android:name=".app.LaunchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
... Other activities
</application>
```

MyTheme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/button_back</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: What do you want to do?? You want to show LaunchActivity for 1 sec and then starting the HomeActivity??

Comment: Yes, but that is not the problem. My problem is that the layout is just blank page, instead of what is written in activity_launch.xml

Comment: That's because you're doing a Thread.sleep in your onCreate method : the interface is created only once onCreated has been completely called. Put your sleep outside of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this in onCreate() method of LaunchActivity.

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
```